# Why pandas dataframe to_dict("records") performance is bad compared to another naive implementation?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

Pandas to_dict("records") seems to have a much inferior performance compared to a naive implementation. Below is the code snippet of my implementation:

```
def fast_to_dict_records(df):
    data = df.values.tolist()
    columns = df.columns.tolist() 
    return [
        dict(zip(columns, datum))
        for datum in data
    ]
```

To compare the performance, try the below code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_test = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.normal(size=(10000, 300)),
    columns=range(300)
)

%timeit df_test.to_dict('records')
%timeit fast_to_dict_records(df_test)
```

And the outputs are:

```
2.21 s ± 71.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
293 ms ± 15.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Namely my implementation is ~7.5 faster than pandas native implementation. Also, it should be easy to verify that the two methods provide the same result. I have also tested the performance against different sizes of dataframes and seems like my implementation is consistently outperform its counterpart (although the magnitude might differ).

I am curious am I missing anything here? I am just not convinced that pandas native implementation performance, which under my impression was quite competitive, can be beaten that much by a not-so-complicated alternative...

Comment: you could take a peek at the source code to see where the difference is

Comment: In my opinion, the reason is that native implementation iter over pandas structures, and they are heavy to handle, in your instead you convert in one single operation all data to python native types and from that point, other operations are really fast.
try to convert every single row of the data frame, my expectation is that is will fit better the native performance.

Comment: Nice discovery! I think we can open a ticket on GitHub to fix this performance issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Pandas is mostly written in *pure Python* like your implementation although it often use *vectorized Numpy calls* internally to speed the computation up. Unfortunately, this is *not case here*. As a result, the Pandas implementation is *inefficient*. Your implementation is *faster*, but it requires *more memory*.

---

### In-depth study:

You can find the implementation of `to_list` [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/895f0b4022562d33e485c5d4eab1014d18656e0c/pandas/core/frame.py#L1611). It iterate over data using `itertuples` internally (see [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/895f0b4022562d33e485c5d4eab1014d18656e0c/pandas/core/frame.py#L1211) for its code). The resulting (slightly simplified) Pandas code at the date of the 12th march 2021 is the following:

```py
def maybe_box_native(value: Scalar) -> Scalar:
    if is_datetime_or_timedelta_dtype(value): # branch never taken here
        value = maybe_box_datetimelike(value)
    elif is_float(value):                     # branch always taken here
        value = float(value)                  # slow manual conversion for EACH values!
    elif is_integer(value):
        value = int(value)
    elif is_bool(value):
        value = bool(value)
    return value

def pandas_to_list(df):
    # From itertuples:
    fields = list(df.columns)
    arrays = [df.iloc[:, k] for k in range(len(df.columns))]
    tmpRes = zip(*arrays)

    # From to_list:
    columns = df.columns.tolist()
    rows = (dict(zip(columns, row)) for row in tmpRes)
    return [dict((k, maybe_box_native(v)) for k, v in row.items()) for row in rows]
```

Your implementation generates a big temporary list in memory using `to_list` while Pandas works with Python generators internally. This list should not be a problem in practice in most simple cases since the `dict` should eventually be much bigger.

However, `to_list` (in your implementation) also converts the Numpy types efficiently using **vectorized Numpy calls** internally while Pandas use a very slow approach. Indeed, **Pandas checks and converts all the value one by one** using the `maybe_box_native` *pure Python function* and slow if/else... It is thus not surprising that the Pandas implementation is slower. That being said, note that your code might behave differently with dates.

The current Pandas implementation is inefficient and it can clearly be improved in the future (possibly without requiring much more memory).

Comment: Indeed. After checking the pandas implementation, I can see that it is doing more loops. Thanks!